# A person who can sit for a long time

Tags: meaning

Is there a single adjective to describe a person who can sit for a long time doing homework, reading or working?

For example, "Jane is so ... . She can sit at her desk for hours without getting tired of sitting."

Comment: "Jane is so focused..."

Comment: Does it really need to be an adjective, or would you also accept something like, "Jane has ..."?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe it doesn't necessarily have to be an adjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to "assiduous" (and to adjectives in general for the intended meaning), I would suggest the phrase "**(to) have sitzfleisch**". The term [Sitzfleisch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/german-english/sitzfleisch) comes from German and literally means "sitting flesh" or "flesh to sit on". In addition to its literal meaning (the posterior), it refers to the ability to remain seated for a long time, especially the ability to finish a long task that is to be completed while you remain seated. (See also [sitzfleisch in the English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sitzfleisch) and in the [German Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sitzfleisch).)

The article ["Sitzfleisch: The German concept to get more work done"](http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20180903-to-have-sitzfleisch---its-a-professional-compliment) on BBC Capital writes:

> When someone says you have sitzfleisch, it’s usually a professional compliment: it means they believe you’re capable of focusing long enough to complete a tough project or finish whatever work needs to be done. If you don’t have sitzfleisch, however, that is a particularly evocative way of suggesting you might be flighty or unable to concentrate on one thing at a time.

Comment: Great phrase! Thank you! Danke schön!

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably not going to hit the nail on the head with this one, but the adjective [**assiduous**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assiduous) sounds like something that's not exactly, but very, very close to what you're looking for:

> ## assiduous
>
> adjective
>
> 1. constant; unremitting:
>
>    *assiduous reading.*
> 2. constant in application or effort; working diligently at a task; persevering; industrious; attentive:
>
>    *an assiduous student.*

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is a pretty obscure word -- I'm a native English-speaking humanities major and I would have to look this up if I encountered it without a clear enough context.

Comment: @Sparksbet Thank you for your comment. I believe you. I myself learned about its existence a couple of days ago. The word is obviously not in everyday use, but the OP didn't say anything about how common the word they're looking for should be.

Comment: True -- I don't really know any more common word that has the meaning they're looking for.

Comment: *diligent* (mentioned in this definition) is also a good one.